# After accidentally removing file and adding it back I can't compare anymore

Tags: svn, subversive

I'm using eclipse subversive. I accidentally remove a file from my local svn folder, refreshed the synchronize view, then added it back again, and refreshed the svn synchronize view.

Now when I right-click on the file and select 'open in compare editor' I get the following error message:

```
Get content for 'editor.cfm' failed.
svn: Cannot read from 'C:\workspace\abc\.svn\text-base\editor.cfm.svn-base': C:\workspace\abc\.svn\text-base\editor.cfm.svn-base'
(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

When I check in the folder I see that instead of file `editor.cfm.svn-base` there is the file `editor.cfm.svn-revert`.

How do I fix this problem? It seems that I have to somehow add the file back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

- Made a backup copy of the file
- Reverted the local file in svn
- Copied the backup over the reverted file

Now everything is back to normal.